# Why citations in footnote aren't displayed?

Tags: cross-referencing, footnotes, quotation, rmarkdown

I'm writing a paper in Rmarkdown. I have the following problem: citations don't appear in the footnote. This is an example:

[image]

while in the main text citations appear correctly with cross-referencing:

[image]

This is my setup:

```
---
title: "Title"
author:
  - name: Rollo99

abstract: |
 Abstract

keywords: key
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
bibliography: library.bib
references:
link-citations: yes
linkcolor: blue
output: 
  rticles::elsevier_article:
    number_sections: yes
header-includes:

- \setcitestyle{numbers}
- \usepackage{amsmath}
- \usepackage{hyperref}
- \usepackage{graphicx}
- \usepackage[section]{placeins}
- \usepackage{float}
- \usepackage[font=small, skip=1pt]{caption}
- \usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
- \usepackage{amssymb}
- \usepackage{inputenc}
- \usepackage{placeins}
- \usepackage{blindtext}
- \usepackage{setspace}
- \usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3cm, left=3cm, right=3cm]{geometry}
- \usepackage{amsmath}
- \usepackage{amssymb}
- \usepackage{mathrsfs}
- \usepackage{longtable}
- \usepackage{graphicx,booktabs}
- \usepackage{ragged2e}
- \usepackage{csquotes}
- \usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
- \usepackage{xpatch}
- \setlength\parindent{0pt}
- \usepackage{appendix}
- \usepackage{multirow}
- \DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{argmin}
- \usepackage{csquotes}
- \usepackage{booktabs,caption}
- \usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
- \usepackage[12pt]{moresize}
- \usepackage{setspace}
- \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

---

I tried solutions avalibla, but they don't apply to my case. How can I fix it?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this?

https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2846

You're welcome!

Comment: Well done Watson! I can feel your microecon mind !